# Inserting Values Into HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-table

I am trying to create a simple table that will allow users to input their username and a value and see their value added immediately to the table.

Picture:

[image]

Current Code:

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <style>
        table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}
    </style>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="page for t1 fantasy sports">
        <title>T1 Fantasy</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>T1 Fantasy Sports</h1>
        <table style="width=100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Total Points</th>
            <th>Total Points Yesterday</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>nmaron</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>memaron</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>youngplum13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>burstometry</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kermit</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <form>
        Username: <br>
            <input type="text" name="username"></br>
        Points Scored: <br>
        <input type="number" name="points"></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Very new to this. I am not trying to do anything complex, I need the values that the user inputs to be placed next to their respective username.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to put the number under the correct column and then augment the number for the total column. I don't know how to increase a specific cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple solution you can use jquery, here you have the solution for your example [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/nNeEbQTlKuCTmRFfQxh5?p=preview)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add-points").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = $("input[name=username]").val();
    var newPoints = parseInt($("input[name=points]").val());

    $("#puntuation tr").each(function(i, row) {
        var $row = $(row);
        var user = $row.find(".playerName").html();
        if(user === username) {
            var $totalPoints = $row.find(".totalPoints");
            var $yesterday = $row.find(".yesterday");
            $yesterday.html($totalPoints.html());
            var currentPoints = $totalPoints.html();
            if(currentPoints) {
                $totalPoints.html(parseInt(currentPoints)+newPoints); 
            } else {
                $totalPoints.html(newPoints);
            }
        }
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for except that I need to figure out how to control which column it is posted under. For example, if on Day 1 a user submits 2 points it should post under both columns. However, on Day 2 when a user submits 3, the first column (score) should be augmented by 3 totaling 5 and then the second column should show the number 3. This is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: Look now the plunkr!

Comment: Damn, that was exactly what I needed. Can you recommend a website that provides a good tutorial? I can't believe how much I struggled with this. Nonetheless, thank you for taking the time to write that, I wasn't anywhere close.

Comment: @ChasenBettinger https://www.pluralsight.com/ has good courses for programming, you can start with some jquery lessons. Please mark my answer as correct here.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode (use Javascript, which you can put in the head portion of the document):

```
On form submission,  
foundMatch = false;
For each row excluding the headers {,  
  if(the contents of the first <td> == the entered username)  {  
    add a <td> to that row containing the value of the points field  
    and record that you found a match (foundMatch = true).  
    Break out of the iteration unless a duplicate username in the table should also get the score added.
  }  
}  

If you reach the end of the table not having found a match (foundMatch == false), {  
  add a row to the table with the values of the username and points fields.  
}
```

I'm only providing pseudocode here to encourage you to understand your own coding problem better and put a bit more effort in on future questions.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How do I integrate this into the html file?

Comment: @ChasenBettinger You have to write the javascript first, but you can put it in the head portion of your HTML document once you do.